# User shell command to parse the value of csv string

Tags: shell

I want to parse csv string with shell command. For example I have the csv string like `csvstr=name1,name2,name3`. I want to traverse each value in a loop and execute another command on each value.

Comment: How complicated is your CSV? Do the columns contain quotes, the delimiter (comma), whitespace? Otherwise, `perl -aF, -nle 'system(q(/path/to/command),@F)'` could be enough. Alternatively, I recommend a robust CSV parser like https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IFS=','

for i in "${csvstr}"
do 
echo $i  # This gives you each value separated on ',' in csvstr
<Run your other command>
done
```